# Is it possible to use fonts for Images/icons in Android

Tags: android, fonts, android-drawable

I Just know that we can use fonts for text only by using the [TypeFace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) class. But can anyone please confirm me about images.

I have added all my custom fonts(.ttf) inside asset/fonts folder. Placed some ImageViews in their appropriate place in my app. And trying to use fonts to set images on them.

I have googled for a long time, but unfortunately unable to find any satisfied hint or help.

Can any one please help me to go forward from the current step.

Comment: I guess you have some mix stuff there. TypeFace define what the text look like. TextView show text. ImageView show images. TypeFace are not images, they cannot be shown on ImageView.

Comment: @Budius Thanks for reply.But my custom font contains iconic characters i.e each character is like one image. and for each character I have one code also..so can I get the iconic character through this code..any idea.?

Comment: They're still just a font. You have to find the code for it and put that code in the TextView, `setText` method. For example, the code for a line break is "\n".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Placed some ImageViews in their appropriate place in my app. And trying to use fonts to set images on them.

`ImageView` accepts images. Whatever set of pixels or vectors are in a font, they are not images from the standpoint of `ImageView`. The simplest way to display material from a custom font is through `TextView`, though you are welcome to implement your own `Drawable` and attempt to use that with an `ImageView`, or draw straight to the `Canvas` (e.g., in a custom widget).

Comment: I respect your answer and satisfied for TextView, but still confused on implementing own  drawable  part. Can you explain a little that how to do that for imageview.

Comment: @RanjitPati: `Drawable` is an abstract class, representing "things that know how to draw". An `ImageView` displays `Drawable` objects, whether those come from bitmaps, XML-defined drawable types like `ShapeDrawable`, etc. You are welcome to create your own subclass of `Drawable` that overrides `draw()` and uses 2D drawing APIs to render "text" from your font on a supplied `Canvas`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use font awesome. Import the android-iconify/1.0.6  jar library from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/joanzapata/android/android-iconify/1.0.6/
and you can use IconTextView

```
  <IconTextView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="{fa-mobile}"
            android:textColor="#9fd46c"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i have my own custom font. +1 for the IconTextView.